# What is difference between #define and #pragma in C

Tags: c

As of now i know that #define is standard and #pragma is not standard but what is other difference between them.

Comment: Different semantics

Answer (score 3):

Try Microsoft's link [for Pragma](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx) and [for Define](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teas0593.aspx)

## Define:

> The #define directive causes the compiler to substitute token-string for each occurrence of identifier in the source file. The identifier is replaced only when it forms a token.

### Pragma:

> The pragma directive is used to access compiler-specific preprocessor
> extensions. A common use of #pragma is the #pragma once directive,
> which asks the compiler to include a header file only a single time,
> no matter how many times it has been imported